# Media Player Crashing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am new to programming and upon referring google's dev site I came up with a simple media player that plays the file selected by the user. The app seems to been running fine when choosing the file to be played for the first time but crashes right after selecting a file for the second time. I have pasted the code below. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
private static int Reqs =1; 
private String a; 
MediaPlayer md=new MediaPlayer(); 

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
Button Start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); 
final Button Stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3); 
final Button Pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 
final Button Select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4); 

Pause.setEnabled(false); 
Stop.setEnabled(false); 

Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 

md.start(); 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing",              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
Pause.setEnabled(true); 
Stop.setEnabled(true); 
} 
}); 

Stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
Pause.setEnabled(false); 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopped",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
md.stop(); 
} 
}); 

Pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
md.pause(); 

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
} 
}); 

Select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
intent.setType("audio/mpeg"); 
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose"), Reqs); 
} 
}); 
} 

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent       data) { 
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
if (requestCode <= Reqs && resultCode ==-1) { 
Uri videoUri = data.getData(); 
a = videoUri.toString(); 

md.setDataSource(a); //try-catch surrounding it
md.prepare();        //try-catch surrounding it
} 
} 
}
```

Comment: Probably you are not calling reset or release before re-using MediaPlayer object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `reset()` to reset the state of the `MediaPlayer` object.

As the Android's documentation states:

> In order to reuse a MediaPlayer object that is in the Error state and recover from the error, reset() can be called to restore the object to its Idle state.

Check it at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: Thanks,  mane. Can't  believed I  missed that. It did  it for me.